# "Contagem" X "Contação", "Lavagem" X "Lavação", afinal existe uma maneira correta de substantivar um verbo?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, verbos, substantivos

O verbo contar possui [diversos significados](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/contar) e a forma substantiva mais comum é [contagem](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/contagem), porém quando a idéia a ser transmitida é o fato de contar histórias para crianças, vejo comumente o uso de *contação de histórias* (sendo usado, p.ex. em [artigos acadêmicos pedagógicos](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj_zdP8zY_SAhVBfZAKHdRTADkQFgghMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fperiodicos.pucminas.br%2Findex.php%2Fpedagogiacao%2Farticle%2FviewFile%2F8477%2F7227&usg=AFQjCNFULzl7vXY-FM4JQhsrHM6dzCFsrw&sig2=9xUoy8yZFZjVf-6xXeoLLg&bvm=bv.146786187,d.Y2I), em [sites voltados para professores](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj_zdP8zY_SAhVBfZAKHdRTADkQFgg5MAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lendo.org%2Fguia-definitivo-contacao-historias%2F&usg=AFQjCNHa-rlGk28ocL_QZCxIniPdgRT9aA&sig2=RYC9LUDiRm341Va8-EAfGw&bvm=bv.146786187,d.Y2I) ou [notícias jornalísticas](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj_zdP8zY_SAhVBfZAKHdRTADkQFghZMAg&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcatraquinha.catracalivre.com.br%2Fgeral%2Faprender%2Findicacao%2Fcurso-gratuito-ensina-contacao-de-historias-para-publico-em-geral%2F&usg=AFQjCNGGRG9dkH-F08phYiuM6UeXG-RmXw&sig2=_K-Au08dv5UZr_Rcq4r0KA&bvm=bv.146786187,d.Y2I)).

Fenômeno semelhante ocorre com o verbo [lavar](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/lavar), sendo comum o substantivo [lavagem](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/lavagem), porém, recentemente, ouvi em uma rádio que o substantivo *lavação* tem sido usado quando se refere à higienização de veículos (p.ex. em [notícias jornalísticas](http://ndonline.com.br/joinville/noticias/lavacoes-de-carros-precisam-atender-normas-ambientais-para-funcionamento-em-joinville), e mesmo [divulgação de empresas que prestam tal serviço](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=lava%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20automotiva&rlz=1C1JZAP_enBR691BR693&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=662&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPtbmoz4_SAhWLHZAKHch3BCYQsAQISQ)). O uso de lavação de carros seria comum no estado de Santa Catarina (Sul do Brasil), o que uma pesquisa no google parece corroborar, visto que as auto-sugestões incluem cidades deste estado.

Minha dúvida é, estariam todas as formas *lavagem* e *lavação* e *contagem* e *contação* corretas? Outros verbos aceitam mais de uma forma substantiva?

Comment: É que existem muitos sufixos que têm significados muito parecidos. Pode haver uma regra para nos dizer qual usar (segundo a fonética, etc) mas não há uma sempre. Para referir ao acto de fazer algo, *quase* não há diferença alguma entre *-ação*, *-agem* ou inclusive às vezes um simples *--ado*. As diferenças podem surgir de quando entrou uma palavra na língua segundo os sufixos mais comuns no momento (*-agem* vem logo na história da língua, via o francês). Quando fica como neologismo, o normal é coexisterem várias formas até ganhar uma delas, mas não há uma regra fixa para determinar qual será.

Comment: Contação de história é narração. Contagem usa-se para contar coisas, itens, materiais, etc. Contagem de histórias seria o mesmo que contar o número de histórias.

Comment: Já ouvi o uso de lavação mas no sentido de lavagem frenética, lavagem exagerada, lavagem intensa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tanto [*lavação*](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=lemma&lemma=5078) quanto [*lavagem*](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=lemma&lemma=58102) constam do brasileiro [Vocabulário Ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa](http://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/busca-no-vocabulario) e do europeu Vocabulário Ortográfico Português. Como ambas as bases de dados são consideradas oficiais pela república de seu respectivo país, podemos considerá-las gramaticalmente corretas.

Já em relação a *contação*, nenhum dos dois Vocabulários lista-a (mas listam [*contagem*](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=lemma&lemma=7796)), e os principais dicionários de ambos os países também não a listam. Acho seguro afirmar que ela é gramaticalmente incorreta.

A teoria mais aceita entre os gramaticistas e dicionaristas brasileiros, no momento, é a de que o uso continuado de uma expressão determina a corretude da mesma, e não o contrário. Em outras palavras, embora *contação* possa ser considerada incorreta pela norma culta, nada a impede de ser reconhecida daqui a alguns anos devido à aceitação social.

Alguns exemplos de ações representadas por mais de um substantivo: `iniciação`/`inicialização`, `homossexualismo`/`homossexualidade`, `descobrimento`/`descoberta`, `ardência`/`ardimento`, `desflorestamento`/`desflorestação`.

Comment: iniciação verbo iniciar; inicialização verbo inicializar (aportuguesamento desnecessário. óbvio); homossexualismo = sufixo de doença ismo (em desuso); exemplos ruins

Comment: @AndréLyra não quis entrar nos detalhes políticos da língua. No papel, significam a mesma ação.

Comment: heterossexualidade / homossexualidade são os conceitos atuais e não são ações, nem mesmo com -ismo. ao se falar do idioma tem de entender o processo de formação de palavras.

Comment: @AndréLyra ficarei feliz em editar se você tiver uma fonte. Os dicionários e os Vocabulários reconhecem ambas as grafias.

Comment: Dois textos sobre o assunto [Veja](http://veja.abril.com.br/blog/sobre-palavras/homossexualismo-ou-homossexualidade/) e [Portugues e Tal](http://portuguesetal.blogspot.com.br/2014/01/sufixo-ismo.html)